Can I convert CAN DBC file to ARxml? if yes how can I convert it or which tool I can use?
i want to convert can dbc file to arxml.
I tried on many softwares like can db++ etc but it is converting into xml file I want arxml. If anyone has information about it please update here as soon as possible. please consider my request thanks.

Vector usually bundles their LegacyDb2SystemDescrConverter with their SIPs. This also has the advantage to give further infos by VSDE extension files into the conversion. Not sure what ETAS (ISOLAR-A/B) or Elektrobit provide. There is also the https://github.com/ebroecker/canmatrix . In the end, I have not come around a single conversion tool though besides Vectors, which handles all the DBC to ARXML differences properly, e.g. Attributes, Diag/Xcp/Nm and TimeSync messages. For the last parts, they end up as ISignalIPdus instead of GeneralPurposePdus/IPdus with correct categories.
